# Unable to see request output with python

Tags: python

I am learning python and developing a simple rest client in order to retrieve inventory data from webserver. I passed authentication steps(Retrieving TGT&ST tickets and received LOGIN SUCCESS). After that, I wanted to run some inventory request it shows only a http template...When I run this code in postman it works correctly. I even copy-paste code snippet from postman, still not giving correct text to me.

Since secure communication set up, I had to avoid ssl verification but it shouldn't be important I guess.

```
url = "https://xxx.xx.xx.xx:8443/oms1350/data/otn/networkElement"
payload = ""
headers = {
'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
'cache-control': "no-cache",
'Accept': "application/json"
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify = False)
print(response.stats_code)
print(response.text)
```

However, output is not data.seems like a web template:

[Screenshot of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsTgY.png)

I tried the same request with postman it shows information:

```
{"reqCompletionStatus":0,"requestId":0,"clientName":null,"clientLocation":null,"clientUser":null,"sessionId":"","mdcId":null,"sequenceNum":0,"moreToCome":false,"messages":[],"errcde":null,"errorParams":null,"nextTasks":null,"items":[{"className":"networkElement","id":"4289","key":"networkElement/4289","guiLabel":"TEST_tn_34_extn_VNE1","NeId":"4289","NeName":"TEST_tn_34_extn_VNE1","NeType":"BBOX_NE","compositeNodeName":"TEST_tn_34_extn_VNE1","activityState":"activitystate.15","commsStatus":"CS_DOWN","managementType":"NMT_UNKNOWN","configDownloadStatus":"DownloadDisabled","swVersion":"R1.0","nprNeId":"1594","neModel":"BBOX_NE","controllerModel":"NPR","controllerName":"OTNE_2_NPR","controllerSwVersion":"R1.0","neName
```

How can I see the same output in python shell? Appricate for your helps in advance.

Regards,
Volkan

Comment: Are you using the correct HTTP method? Form data can only be sent via POST – it does not make sense to include any payload or Content-Type with a GET request.

Comment: I am using GET request...Also tried without payload and content type...No success..

Comment: You should also try `response.content` or  `response.json` ([Requests QuickStart](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)).